# Running an application as Windows Service requires Administrator rights or not?

Tags: c++, windows, service

I have created a Windows-service in Visual C++ 2010. it basically looks for a file and if exists then delete it.

Now if I run that application as administrator then the file is successfully deleted from the location. but if I install it as Windows service and runs the service, then then the file is detected but not deleted, even the service is running as on Local System.

Now My question is whether Windows-services require top-most privileges or it runs with the highest privileges??

Comment: The permissions may not be the problem.  Add some logging so that you can see what error code is returned from the call to `DeleteFile`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Windows services can run with any account, and therefore with virtually no rights at all.

Of course, if you want to delete a file, NTFS will check its Access Control List (ACL). When Administrator does have deletion rights but Local System does not, you'd have the observed behavior. But what matters is the file ACL, services aren't special.